# How to fix 'The the message received was unexpected or badly formatted'

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, httpclient, discord.net

I've been trying to fix this problem for a while now, but everything I've tried is useless. I tried HttpClientHandler but still getting the error!

Error messages:

> SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception
>
> Authentication failed, see inner exception
>
> The the message received was unexpected or badly formatted

```
[Command("stats")] 
public async Task Profileosu([Remainder]string username = null)
{
    try
    {
        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler,disposeHandler: true);
        List<Player> player = new List<Player>();
        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path, encoding: Encoding.UTF8).ToList();
        string id = "";
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            string[] readed = line.Split(",");

            Player newPlayer = new Player();
            newPlayer.id = readed[0];
            newPlayer.osuname = readed[1];

            player.Add(newPlayer);
        }

        if (username is null)
        {
            id = Context.User.Id.ToString();
            username = Context.User.Username;
        }
        else if (Context.Message.MentionedUsers.Count > 0)
        {
            username = Context.Message.MentionedUsers.First().Username;
            id = Context.Message.MentionedUsers.First().Id.ToString();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < player.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (player[i].id == id)
            {
                username = player[i].osuname;
            }
        }

        string url = $"https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k={k}&u={username}";
        string osuProf = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        dynamic osuProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(value: osuProf);
        string pp_raw = osuProfile[0]["pp_raw"];
        string country = osuProfile[0]["country"];
        string user_id = osuProfile[0]["user_id"];
        string joinDate = osuProfile[0]["join_date"];
        string rank = osuProfile[0]["pp_rank"];
        string countryRank = osuProfile[0]["pp_country_rank"];
        string accuracy = osuProfile[0]["accuracy"];
        string playcount = osuProfile[0]["playcount"];
        string userName = osuProfile[0]["username"];



        embed.WithThumbnailUrl($"https://a.ppy.sh/{user_id}");
        embed.WithAuthor($"{username} #{rank}, {pp_raw}PP", Context.Guild.CurrentUser.GetAvatarUrl(), $"https://osu.ppy.sh/users/{user_id}");
        embed.WithDescription($"Join date:{joinDate}\nCountry:{country} #{countryRank}\n");
        embed.WithFooter($"Accuray:{double.Parse(accuracy):F2}%\t\tPlaycount:{playcount}");
        embed.WithColor(154, 255, 0);

        await ReplyAsync($"", false, embed.Build());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        embed.WithAuthor("An error occurred");
        embed.WithDescription("This player doesn't exist! Please check the username and try again!");
        embed.WithColor(255, 0, 0);
        await ReplyAsync($"", false, embed.Build());
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        if (ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
        }    
    }
}
```

I learning c# from scratch and I am very beginner in the language so please explain what's the problem.

Comment: which line is the error happening on?

Comment: Tbh I don't know

Comment: I think it happens on the string osuProf = await client.GetStringAsync(url); line because I use this on other commands as well and there happens too

Comment: Doesn't the full error message give you a line number?

Comment: No it doesn't give me line number https://imgur.com/a/ens4bd7

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening due to the `clientHandler` you define and use.

For communication with the OSU API you would not really need this either. 
So instead, you could go ahead and let the `HttpClient` handle this for you.

So instead of:

```
clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler,disposeHandler: true);
```

You can define the `HttpClient` as follows:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

As you now no longer define the disposeHandler, it would be a good practice to either add a [Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally) to your try catch.

Or by applying a `using` to the `HttpClient`.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    string url = $"https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user?k={Key}&u=d3ullist";
    string osuProf = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    dynamic osuProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(value: osuProf);
}
```

Which will end up with the dynamic object as you where previously expecting it.

[image]

Comment: @Citrom Are you sure you are using the correct `key`?

Comment: Yes I use the right key, but the weird thing is that there is no consistency with this error because most of the times it works just as it should, but like 1 out of 50 times it's a  random SSL error and after that it works just as nothing happened

Comment: Sounds like it is more likely an issue with your internet, or it's relevant configuration such as firewall, out bound rate limits or the likes.

Comment: That's what I've feared of! Anyways thank you for your help! I try to figure out what causes this